# flash nodejs does not display

Tags: node.js, flash

I am not sure about the syntax, but **flash is not displaying** correctly...

I use **express-flash-2**, also tried other libraries...

```
router.post('/changepassword',ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res){
  if(req.body.newpwd ==  req.body.newpwdb){
    db.query(SqlString.format("Select password FROM Userdata.users WHERE id=?",[req.user.id]), function(error, result){

      if(bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.pwd, result[0].password)){
        db.query(SqlString.format("SELECT * FROM Userdata.insecpwd WHERE password=?",[req.body.newpwd]), function(er,re){
            if (!re[0]){
              db.query(SqlString.format("SELECT salt FROM Userdata.salts WHERE userid=?",[req.user.id]), function(e,r){
                if (e) throw e;
                var hash = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.newpwd, r[0].salt);
                var sql = 'UPDATE Userdata.users SET password=? WHERE id =?';
                db.query(SqlString.format(sql,[hash,req.user.id]),function(err,re){
                  if (err) throw err;
                });
              });
              req.flash('msg','PWD changed');
            }else {
              req.flash('error','New PWD not secure enough');
            }
          });
      }else{
        req.flash('error','Old PWD incorrect');
      }
    });
  }else{
    req.flash('error','PWDS do not match');
  }
  res.redirect("/users/settings");
});
```

Is the **code wrong**, or did i use **flash the wrong** way? Thanks

Comment: Paul, what is more alarming is the potential for SQL injection in this script. Recommend you research this and edit. Look here: https://www.netsparker.com/blog/web-security/sql-injection-cheat-sheet/

Comment: Thanks, @Bibberty i edited the code...

Comment: Sounds good, switch to using parametized queries, it will be much safer.

Comment: Actually the second sql query is the only command with user input; is parametizing then really necessary? As far as i got it is only preventing sql injections with multiple parameters, isn't it? @Bibberty

Comment: Paul there are 3 queries that use the request object. Do not worry about if it is user input. Anything from a request should be considered potentially malicious